# SwiftUI: Match answer index with option index in Quiz game

Tags: swiftui

I'm building a quiz game and am fairly new to SwiftUI. When the quiz is over, I'd like the user to be able to see all the correct answers. Basically, I want to list all questions with the correct answer, but I'm not sure how to match the answer index (Int) with the correct option (String).

Any help is appreciated!

Here's my JSON Structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "question": "Heres a question title",
        "category": "sports",
        "answer": 0,
        "options": [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D"
        ]
    }
    ...
]
```

Here's my Model:

```
struct Question: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id: String
    var question: String
    var category: String
    var answer: Int
    var options: [String]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, question, category, answer, options
    }
    
    static var allQuestions: [Question] = Bundle.main.decode("quizquestions2022.json")
}
```

And here's the sheet view where I want to list all answers:

```
struct AnswerSheetView: View {
    @StateObject var gameManager = GameManagerVM()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            ForEach(gameManager.allQuestions, id: \.self) {  question in
                VStack(spacing: 16) {
                    CategoryTagView(name: question.category, size: 12)
                    Text(question.question)
                    Text("\(question.answer)")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGreen))
                }
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray6))
                .cornerRadius(24)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color(UIColor.black).ignoresSafeArea())
        .navigationTitle("Facit")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like this approach, to match the answer index (Int) with the correct option (String):

```
struct Question: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id: String
    var question: String
    var category: String
    var answer: Int
    var options: [String]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, question, category, answer, options
    }
    
    // this should be in your GameManagerVM, not here
    static var allQuestions: [Question] = Bundle.main.decode("quizquestions2022.json")
    
    func theAnswer() -> String {   // <--- here
        return (answer >= 0 && answer < options.count) ? options[answer] : ""
    }
}

struct AnswerSheetView: View {
    @StateObject var gameManager = GameManagerVM()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            ForEach(gameManager.allQuestions, id: \.self) {  question in
                VStack(spacing: 16) {
                    CategoryTagView(name: question.category, size: 12)
                    Text(question.question)
                    // --- here
                    Text(question.theAnswer()).foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGreen)) 
                }
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray6))
                .cornerRadius(24)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color(UIColor.black).ignoresSafeArea())
        .navigationTitle("Facit")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

Comment: if my answer worked for you, please consider marking it as correct, thank you.